# Automate the end of a script that waits for you to press ENTER

Tags: linux, bash, expect

I'd like to be able to use Cron to automate the execution of CopyConsole, the program that performs the synchronization of files on the server's Copy.com

The problem is that the execution is not terminates while the ENTER key is not pressed.

I've tried various forms of script, the best of all was this, but without success:

```
#!/bin/bash

timeout=600

expect() {
   local expect="$1" send="$2"
   local delim="${expect:(-1):1}"
   local buffer="" block=""
   while read -u3 -r -t$timeout -d "$delim" block; do
      buffer="$buffer$block$delim"
      case "$buffer" in
         *"$expect")
            echo "$send" 1>&3
            return
            ;;
      esac
   done
}

exec 3<>/usr/local/copy.com/copy_sync.sh
expect "All Files Up To Date" "\r"
```

Can anyone help me find a solution, please? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried looking for a non-interactive/batch mode switch in this program? Can you simply run `yes "" | /usr/local/copy.com/copy_sync.sh` to feed it infinite line feeds?

Comment: +1 for most interesting bash question (I've seen) today. As with 1/2 my advice, you can see what is happening if  you turn on shell debugging with `set -vx`, but you probably knew that ;-).  Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED!

Have to use "#!/usr/bin/expect" and execute with "spawn"

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 600
spawn /usr/local/copy.com/x86_64/CopyConsole -u=mail@copyaccount -r=/var/backups/copy.com -p=password
expect "All Files Up To Date" { send "\r"}
```

Thanks for comments.